# What is the reason using "always" in the present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, future-constructions

I saw a movie with its title "We have always lived in the castle".

If they meant to describe the pronoun "we" are living there until they die, why didn't they use future tense then?

> We will always live in the castle.
> *No?*

I tried to revert the translation from English into my language then into English back using a translator, it showed the suggested translation was using future-tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't describing the future. This falls under the "Actions started in the past and continuing in the present" use of the present perfect as described here: https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/ .